# Want dynamically increase the variables in using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Suppose I have entered *N* servers as input.

I want based on server Numbers it should increase variable in line.

Example:

```
cat <<'EOF'>> file.py

Nodes=['app_server1_port','app_server2_port','app_server3_port']   
EOF
```

so on based on server number.

I used FOR LOOP but it won't work.. please  help me.. I have gone through so many ideas but it;s not up to mark.

Comment: Can you show us how you've tried to solve this problem so far? The question is a little unclear, and showing us your attempts might help.

Comment: the question is indeed a quite unclear.  Here is a a for loop example: for i in {1..65535}; do echo "app_server$i_port"; done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
while [  $counter -le $1 ]; do
        STR=$STR",""'app_server$counter""_port'"
        let counter++
done
STR_FINAL="Nodes=["$STR"]"

cat <<EOF>> file.py
$STR_FINAL
EOF

sed -i '0,/,/s///' file.py
```

Comment: It shows error unary operator expected line 3:  [: 1:

Comment: I am using GNU bash, version 4.3 and works here. Try to change while by for, like this: for ((counter = 1 ; counter <= $1 ; counter++ )); do